# Is there a tSQL function that creates a counter after each change of e.g. Value2 orderd by Value1

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to develop a SQL script that creates counter after each change of a value of a table orderd by another column.

See example: The column "ExpectedCalculatedValue" should be calculated by tsQL if its possible

I already tried out functions like 'Rank', or 'Dense_Rank' but I wasn't able solve the problem.

```sql
DECLARE @testTab as TABLE (ID int, [From] datetime, Until datetime, TestID int, 
ExpectedCalculatedValue int)

--TEST DATA
INSERT INTO @testTab VALUES (100, '2019-4-11 11:00', '2019-4-11 11:01', 0, 1)
INSERT INTO @testTab VALUES (100, '2019-4-11 11:01', '2019-4-11 11:11', 200, 2)
INSERT INTO @testTab VALUES (100, '2019-4-11 11:11', '2019-4-11 11:15', 200, 2)
INSERT INTO @testTab VALUES (100, '2019-4-11 11:15', '2019-4-11 11:22', 100, 3)
INSERT INTO @testTab VALUES (100, '2019-4-11 11:22', '2019-4-11 11:45', 200, 4)

select * 
from @testTab a
order by a.[From]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an exact duplicate on the time columns in your data.  That really throws things off.  So, the first thing to do is to introduce a unique number.  In this case, it uses `row_number()`:

```
select a.*,
       sum(case when prev_testid = testid then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by [from], seqnum) as calculated_valued
from (select a.*,
             lag(testid) over (partition by id order by [from], seqnum) as prev_testid
      from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by [from], [until], testid) as seqnum
            from @testTab a
           ) a
     ) a
order by a.[From];
```

However, I would recommend including an `identity` column in the table and using that, as in [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6da255a7bfc6c5510dabc16fea373f44).

Comment: Thx Gordon, perfect. I just also found a solution for that which is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0):

select *, 
sum(case when base.pVal = base.TestID then 0 else 1 end) over(order by base.[From]) as [Counter] 
from 
 (select aa.*, lag(aa.TestID, 1, null) over(order by aa.[From]) as [pVal] 
    from @testTab aa) base